# How am I supposed to progress on the Spaceship level?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I'm currently on the Alien Spaceship, and I have to free Randy from the machine. I've already beaten the aliens in the hallway and taken the elevator.

What am I supposed to do now?

For reference:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing the console to the right of you moves the platform closer to teleport-robot at the bottom-left of the screen.

[image]

This leads to a console you can press.

You must also use the upper teleport-robot to go *up*.  There's a second console in the upper-left of this level to press.

This opens a passageway on the left-side of this level, leading to a boss-fight and the third-and-final console.

Comment: What am I supposed to with the fan, and the hatch? (in the purple tube at the bottom).

Comment: @Kernel The fan can be used to kill the enemies without having to fight them.  I don't know what hatch you're talking about, but you use your alien-probe on the button on the right to open the door to the first console.

Comment: @KernelPanic The hatch won't do anything, i've tried everything possible but everytime you stand on it and activate it, it blows you back up and then closes again. No clue why it is there.

Comment: @Lyrion the hatch allows you to dispatch another one of the Aliens without a fight.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah yes, never thought about it that way. Congrats btw on getting through the anal probing ;)

Comment: @Lyrion I had to cheat. :( I'll write up a how to when I get home, but I'm pretty convinced based on some searching that there is just something wrong with the QTE timing/tolerance for a small subset of PC players.

Answer (score 0):

This part confused me too. In the fan tube go to the to the right there's actually a door a console room.